# Why would sharing a log4net dll cause preferential logging behaviour?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have 2 services that have log4net references and XmlConfigurator set to watch in the AssemblyInfo.cs.

If I run both services on my local machine, both are running from separate directories with Copy Local set to the Log4Net dll.  Both services log fine.

When I push the services to production, they both sit *in the same directory* (I have no say in this), and the behaviour I am seeing is strange.  If one service is started, it logs fine, but the other service does not log at all.  Stranger, if I shut both of them down and start the second, it logs fine, but the first one does not log.

I am assuming that the services can only log one at a time, but this doesn't seem to make any sense since they are separate services.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on here?

Comment: Are the services trying to log to the same file?

Comment: @sgmoore, good question, no, separate files.  The ADO appender is logging to the same table though.

Comment: Probably best to enable Internal logging on log4net. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756125/how-to-track-down-log4net-problems for one way to do this)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the first process is locking the DLL and preventing the other one from loading the same file into its app domain. Just for fun, have you tried making a copy of the DLL, change the name, then have the second service reference that other file? Perhaps something like:

```
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net2nd" />
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I'm hoping to avoid having 2 separate dlls with different names (although it might come to that).  I'm confused why the log4net dll would be locked by the first process, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not that you are looking to change .dll files on the fly, but you might want to look into loading the log4net .dll using the Shadow Copy service.  I got the idea from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/226589/151234

Some helpful hints can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/09/69919.aspx).  It's similar to how ASP.NET works when you drop in a new .dll file.